# Convert Encapsulated PostScript File to PDF in Android

Tags: android, pdf-generation

I want to convert PostScript to PDF but I don't know where to start.

Please suggest me some references or documents from where I can start.

Comment: Are you for a library that does this, or are you trying to implement it yourself from scratch?

Comment: i want library for this.